# Bootstrap 3: Column push after pull

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and am trying to lay out columns like so:

On small screens:

[image]

On larger screens:

[image]

What I have so far:

[image]

The code I'm using is:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7">
      Sidebar top
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5">
      Main content
    </div>

    <!-- I also tried removing the push-7 below with no luck -->
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7"> 
      Sidebar bottom
    </div>                          

  </div>
</div>
```

I am a bit confused because Bootstrap uses `float:left` internally for columns so in the large case I would expect the pushed "sidebar bottom" to float up against the left side of the pulled "main content" since there's room for it. That isn't happening though.

Has anyone solved something similar? Thanks!

Code on Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/YscbG7cX0G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one
HTML structure

```
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col col-sm-5 pull-right" style="background-color:#3B8686;height:50px;">
        Sidebar top
    </div>

    <div class="col col-sm-7" style="background-color:#0B486B;height:100px;">
        Main content
    </div>

    <div class="col col-sm-5" style="background-color:#A8DBA8;height:50px;">
        Sidebar bottom
    </div>

</div>
```

Thank You.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it would be something simple but sometimes you look right past the answer.